# Second Level Cache - Why not cache all entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching, jpa-2.0, second-level-cache

In my experience, I have typically used the shared cache setting:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

My process is to then think about which entities are not expected to change often and those that would benefit from the cache, performance wise, and mark those as `@Cacheable`.  My practice of using selective entity caching is a learned convention, but I don't fully understand this approach.

Why not cache all entities?  When can caching all entities become a detriment?  How can I better gauge this to make a more educated decision?

Comment: what if some entity is being changed often by an external process? wouldn't want to cache it then perhaps (since then you'd have to keep doing refresh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of reasons not to cache entities:

1. When the entities are changed frequently (so you would end up invalidating/locking them in the cache and re-reading them anyway, but you pay an extra cost of cache maintenance which is not low since cache write operations would be frequent).
2. If there are a large number of entity instances to cache and none of them is used more frequently than the others within a given period in time. Then you would basically put instances in cache and evict them soon afterwards to make room for new ones, without reading the cached instances frequently enough to make the cache maintenance costs pay off.
3. If the entities can be changed without Hibernate being aware of that (from an external application or with direct JDBC for example).

Comment: 3.) Should be avoided at all costs and is a pro-reason when it comes to JPA-controlled databases. If the JPA's entity cache is not in sync (done by 3rd party) app, you will and must get ugly exceptions. The fix here is to write JSF views for anything you do over the 3rd party program (like Adminer/phpMyAdmin are). This is what I have been told.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ehcache as your provider

```
<property key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Then you can configure the cache to limit the resources it uses by setting the ehcache.xml to evict the least used entities as required.

Good article here http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/04/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/

Generally speaking I would cache everything, just limit the size of the caches.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Why not cache all entities? When can caching all entities become a
>   detriment? How can I better gauge this to make a more educated
>   decision?

Generally speaking, for an application to benefit from caching the data should be read-mostly. This means that there are multiple reads per a write/update. If this is not the case, as in write-mostly or write-only (think sampling data from a thermometer), the benefit is not there because there is no saving generated by reading hard to get data from memory.

To make an educated decision you can cache everything and then watch hit/miss ratio for the cache. If it's high (+70%), then you are on the right track.

Comment: "Smart" caching (JSR-107) in web container can help reduce communication between web and EJB container. Think about a "list" view where entities are being paginated, e.g. by Primefaces' `<p:dataTable>` tag and filtered/sorted. Each click (read: AJAX reply) will cause an EJB invocation. Here caching inside the web container makes totally sense.